# What is the best way to convert an array of strings into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of emails:

```
['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com']
```

I need to convert it into an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 'a@gmail.com',
        invite_type: 'EMAIL'
    },
    {
        id: 'b@gmail.com',
        invite_type: 'EMAIL'
    },
    {
        id: 'c@gmail.com',
        invite_type: 'EMAIL'
    }
]
```

In order to do that, I have written the following code:

```
$scope.invites = [];

$.each($scope.members, function (index, value) {
    let inviteMember = {
        'id': value,
        invite_type: 'EMAIL'
    }

    $scope.invites.push(inviteMember);
});
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can use [**`jQuery.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) like this:

```
var originalArray = ['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com']

var newArray = jQuery.map(originalArray, function(email) {
    return {
        id: email,
        invite_type:'EMAIL'
    };
});
```

`jQuery.map()` translates all items in a given array into a new array of items. The function I am passing to `jQuery.map()` is called for every element of the original array and returns a new element that is written to the final array.

There is also the native [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is [not supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5). If you're not targeting IE8 or if you use a polyfill, then you can use the native `.map()`:

```
var newArray = originalArray.map(function(email) {
    return {
        id: email,
        invite_type:'EMAIL'
    };
});
```

Comment: please provide some details/comments. So, that people may what is the meaning of this code

Comment: @VikasBansal - please provide an answer yourself rather than simply posting the same comment to all asnwers provided. Whilst it is advisable for posters to provide rationale for their suggested answers, it is infinitely more annoying to see the same comment posted to all answers. I personally liked this answer as soon as it was posted and upvoted it as a simple elegant option to the OP's problem. - oops didn't realise that you are the OP - apologies for that but my comment still stands - a single comment is appropriate - repeating it multiple times is not

Comment: Why use jquery's map over native map?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because the native map is a part of ES6, which is not supported in some (admittedly oudated) browsers.

Comment: You mean every browser except IE8? (Which isn't support by MS themselves...)

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes

Comment: `array.map` is not part of es6, but es5... http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19

Answer (score 1):

This pattern

```
targetArray = []
sourceArray.forEach(function(item) {
    let x = do something with item
    targetArray.push(x)
})
```

can be expressed more concisely with `map`:

```
targetArray = sourceArray.map(function(item) {
    let x = do something with item
    return x
})
```

in your case:

```
$scope.invites = $scope.members.map(function(value) {
     return {
          id: value,
          invite_type: 'EMAIL'
      }
});
```